# Apple Magic Keyboard on Windows FN Key

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, bluetooth

I just go the lastest Apple Magic Keyboard (without number pad).  I want to us it on my Windows 10 laptop.  They keyboard is currently plugged into a USB port because I can't figure out how to connect it to my machine via bluetooth.

I'm trying to use [KeyTweak](https://keytweak.en.softonic.com/) to map some of the functions that Apple doesn't support like

```
fn+up = page up
```

And it looks like the FN key doesn't get registered by my system because keytweak isn't picking it up, on top of that, `fn+up` returns the same code as just the `up` key.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found open source drivers that will do this for me:

https://github.com/samartzidis/WinAppleKey